# Search according to Arabic header in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, arabic

I use **arabic language header** word with one space in **datagridview**.

```
 bs.Filter = string.Format("اسم العقد LIKE '%{0}%' ", txtContractName.Text);
```

There is an error because of the header. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [] around the name like this: [اسم العقد]